# Git Clone Works With CMD But Not With PowerShell

Tags: windows, git, powershell, cmd

I can clone a particular repository with cmd.exe without problems but it fails with PowerShell.

- Git Version: *2.27.0.windows.1*
- Required certificates were added to *git install dir\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt*

**PowerShell Error**

```
PS D:\git> git clone https://foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'foobar'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1352, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1352/1352), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1016/1016), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Malformed encoding found in chunked-encoding
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

**Snippets from my .gitconfig**

I already added the following properties after googling for the problem:

```
file:C:/users/doej1/.gitconfig     core.longpaths=true
file:C:/users/doej1/.gitconfig     core.autocrlf=true
file:C:/users/doej1/.gitconfig     http.postbuffer=524288000
```

Why does it work with cmd.exe but not with PowerShell?

Comment: Are you sure powershell and cmd use the same Git version, with the same .gitconfig?

Comment: @Lorenzo Isidori: I think so: The commands "git config --list --show-origin --show-scope" and "git --version" lead to the same results/outputs when run in cmd and PowerShell